# Make sections align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align everything up, making the sections align and so forth. But I can't seem to get each section to line up.

Here is the link: https://codepen.io/pmurtagh4/pen/GXNzrJ

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0px 24px;
  font-family: 'Petit Formal Script', sans-serif;
  color: #2d3338;
  font-size: 69px;
  line-height: 54px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: none;
}

p {
  color: #05386B;
}

.button {
  width: 35%;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.subtitle {
  margin-right: 89px;
  margin-bottom: 63px;
  margin-left: 89px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  color: #74737a;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.field {
  width: 70%;
  height: 54px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sign-up-form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120%;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 104px;
  background-color: #5CDB95;
  text-align: center;
}

.bars-wrapper {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.bar {
  width: 14.285%;
  height: 7px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.bar._2 {
  background-color: #f2ca27;
}

.bar._3 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.bar._4 {
  background-color: #16a085;
}

.bar._5 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.bar._6 {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}


/*will be using this to hide parts of image
.image-crop {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 260px;
}
*/

.about-section {
  padding: 80px 0 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 50px;
}

.about-section h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 800px;
  color: #033048;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.about-book p {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600px;
}

.aboutus {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Raijin Studios</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bars-wrapper">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar _2"></div>
    <div class="bar _3"></div>
    <div class="bar _4"></div>
    <div class="bar _5"></div>
    <div class="bar _6"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-section">
    <h1 class="heading">Raijin Studios</h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Raijin Studios is excited to announce our new upcoming novella, The Water King.</p>
    <div class="sign-up-form">
      <form name="sign-up"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" max-length="256" reguired="" class="field"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Get Notified"></form>
      <!--This is where an image of the new book will go -->
      <section class="about-section">
        <h2>About The Water King!</h2>
        <p class="about-book">Beginning in a fictional realm, one heir to the worlds throne is casted to earth by his best friend - his brother, the one he trusted most. When losing his memory causes the mysterious man to forget who he his and where he came from, he turns
          to the help of a strange girl who finds him and helps him remeber who he was and where he came from.</p> </section>
      <section class="aboutus">
        <p>This section will be about the fictionous company. Similar to the about pages on websites.</p>
      </section <footer>
      <p>This will be the footer, thanking our users and readers and will display social media icons and copyright.

        <!--i will be added more features and elements to both the footer and the sections of the website. For intereactivity, I am going to try to make the color bar at the top fade in and out as well -->
        </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `margin: auto`, removing `display: block` and setting width to 100% instead of 120% makes it look quite okay. Is this what you were looking for?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdmKWQ

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you are having is because of `.sign-up-form` `width` styling. It is currently set to `120%`, which is making the content weird. Remove it or change it to `100%`.

Second issue I found is related to `font-weight`. The value of it is never in `px`.  Review [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) for more info.

Third issue remove the default margin on the page.

Updated code snippet -

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px 0px 24px;
  font-family: 'Petit Formal Script', sans-serif;
  color: #2d3338;
  font-size: 69px;
  line-height: 54px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: none;
}

p {
  color: #05386B;
}

.button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 5%;
}

.subtitle {
  margin-right: 89px;
  margin-bottom: 63px;
  margin-left: 89px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  color: #74737a;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 54px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sign-up-form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 104px;
  background-color: #5CDB95;
  text-align: center;
}

.bars-wrapper {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.bar {
  width: 14.285%;
  height: 7px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.bar._2 {
  background-color: #f2ca27;
}

.bar._3 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.bar._4 {
  background-color: #16a085;
}

.bar._5 {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.bar._6 {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}


/*will be using this to hide parts of image
.image-crop {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 260px;
}
*/

.about-section {
  padding: 80px 0 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 50px 0px 50px;
}

.about-section h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #033048;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.about-book p {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.aboutus {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: auto;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Raijin Studios</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bars-wrapper">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar _2"></div>
    <div class="bar _3"></div>
    <div class="bar _4"></div>
    <div class="bar _5"></div>
    <div class="bar _6"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-section">
    <h1 class="heading">Raijin Studios</h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Raijin Studios is excited to announce our new upcoming novella, The Water King.</p>
    <div class="sign-up-form">
      <form name="sign-up"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" max-length="256" reguired="" class="field"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Get Notified"></form>
      <!--This is where an image of the new book will go -->




      <section class="about-section">
        <h2>About The Water King!</h2>
        <p class="about-book">Beginning in a fictional realm, one heir to the worlds throne is casted to earth by his best friend - his brother, the one he trusted most. When losing his memory causes the mysterious man to forget who he his and where he came from, he turns
          to the help of a strange girl who finds him and helps him remeber who he was and where he came from.</p> </section>


      <section class="aboutus">
        <p>This section will be about the fictionous company. Similar to the about pages on websites.</p>
      </section>

      <footer>
        <p>This will be the footer, thanking our users and readers and will display social media icons and copyright.</p>
        <!--i will be added more features and elements to both the footer and the sections of the website. For intereactivity, I am going to try to make the color bar at the top fade in and out as well -->
      </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S. A lot of your tags don't have a closing tag. You should fix them as well.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for pointing everything out. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @P.Murtagh Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped solve your issue. Happy coding! :)